# python slice, own implementation

Tags: python

I'm trying to write my own implementation for slice notion, it should work on my own implementation (that i wrote) for single linked list, but after 2 days of trying all day, i can say i have nothing, every thing i  wrote didn't work at all(thats why i didn't post code),
of course its a function that get the list, the start pos, stop pos, and step, it should behave the same as slice(including negative pos and steps), any idea how to start? or some source code for slice?

code(bad attempt):

```
if start is None:
    start = sll.head
if stop is None and dire is False:
    stop = start
    start = sll.head

re_list = List()
pointer = Node(start.get_data())
list_head = pointer
if start is stop:
    re_list.add_first(pointer.get_data())
while start is not None and start is not stop:
    for i in range(abs(step)):
        start = start.get_next()
        if start is None or start is stop:
            break
    if dire is True and start is not None and start is not stop:
        pointer.set_next(Node(start.get_data()))
        pointer = pointer.get_next()
    elif dire is False:
        re_list.add_first(start.get_data())
if dire is True:
    re_list.head = list_head
elif dire is False:
    re_list.head.set_next(pointer)

return re_list
```

thanks

Comment: Can you post all the code, including `List` and `Node`?

Comment: You are encouraged to show what you've tried, even though it doesn't work. That will make the community much more willing to help you to solve every issue you're having. Good luck.

Comment: Do **not** use `is` to compare values. The `is` operator should only be used to check for `None`s. In all other cases change the `is` to `==` and the `is not` to `!=`.